# How to set up a CMake project for a Windows DLL with Unit tests using Google tests

Tags: windows, cmake

I am working on a Windows library, written using C++20, and I want to use CMake and Google test. So I have a top-level directory with just the common stuff, an "`src`" directory with the library's sources, and a "`unittests`" directory with a test. I managed to get everything to build and link, but running the tests fails with "Test TestInterOp failed with exit code 3221225781."

Running the generated test EXE from the commandline gives me several popups complaining about missing DLLs, so I guess that is the problem, but I have no idea what the best way is to solve this.

My top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()
SET(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

project (CsSimConnectInterOp)

enable_testing()

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/refs/tags/v1.14.0.zip
)

# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src $ENV{MSFS_SDK}/SimConnect\ SDK/include)
link_directories($ENV{MSFS_SDK}/SimConnect\ SDK/lib)
link_libraries(SimConnect.lib)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(unittests)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET CsSimConnectInterOp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()
```

The library is very simple at the moment, just:

```
add_library (CsSimConnectInterOp SHARED CsSimConnectInterOp.cpp  CsSimConnectInterOp.h  dllmain.cpp  framework.h  Log.h  Logger.cpp  pch.cpp  pch.h)
```

The `unittests` directory has:

```
add_executable(TestInterOp LogTests.cpp)

add_test(TestInterOp TestInterOp)

target_link_libraries(TestInterOp
 PRIVATE
  CsSimConnectInterOp
  SimConnect.lib
  GTest::gtest
  GTest::gtest_main)
```

So linking is fine, it's just that I need something to help me actually run the tests.

Comment: "Running the generated test EXE from the commandline gives me several popups complaining about missing DLLs" - So, which exact DLLs are missing?

Comment: Sorry to be late responding. Ok, the DLLs it is missing as far as I can see are the CsSimConnectInterOp one and the SimConnect DLL. I fixed that last one by using the "`static`" subdirectory in the SDK's lib. The first one is picked up, but now it throws a security exception. I'm wondering if the MSVC compiler isn't picking up the DLL runtime, because that is sometimes installed where you're not supposed to touch it unless you are a store app. Maybe I should ditch the MSVC compiler and try gcc.

Comment: Please, update the question post with that information. On Stack Overflow the question post should contain all relevant information about the problem. Comments are used only for request such information.